# Dynamically add a list to the sign up page of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am new to RoR and I am trying to implement a kind of content management system. Let's say there is an admin user which creates other users.

I have tried the Devise gem. My first question is how can I use this gem so that the admin user creates other users (entering their info, name, email, password)? Is is programatically correct to let the admin user to go to the sign up page and create new users?

My second question is that, in my application the admin should be able to dynamically add a list of organization names in runtime. Therefore, when creating new user, an organization should be chosen from the organization list for that user. I was thinking about creating an empty database for the organization name, and admin user adds to that database in the runtime. Is it a good way?

Thank you so much,
Amir

Comment: The admin can log, and then you can discriminate what the view is showing depending on some specific data on a record. You can also create a namespace, and filter access depending if a user is an admin or not. A namespace is like a folder of controllers. You can regroup specific controllers for a dedicated function like admin,.. these controllers can have same name as other controllers in the parent/normal folder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, I know how to show different views to different users. What I do not know is how the admin user can create other users? If the admin user can see the sign-up button of Devise, is it the right way to do it?

Comment: I don't know devise. Maybe someone can tell you. For my app, I have both a user controller, and another user controller under admin namespace. Only a logged in user with the admin capability can access this namespace.  In this controller, for example, the index view is available. (Which is not in the normal user controller) aswell, it is possible to amend the admin field. Which is false by default, and not changeable in the normal user controller... it's up to you to decide what can be done.

Comment: As per Nicolas answer, it seems devise send email confirmation. In this case you will need of course to bypass this if devise offers this option, and if desired by you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go but, I could manage to make it work like follow.
In your user model, make sure you have added `:confirmable` in devise.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, ...,
```

Also you need your user table to have the following fields.

```
   t.string   "confirmation_token"
   t.datetime "confirmed_at"
   t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
```

Then in your user controller add the following method.

```
def create_new_account
  @new_user = User.new(user_params)
  if @new_user.valid?
    @new_user.skip_confirmation!
    @new_user.confirmed_at = nil
    if @user.save
     render action: "some_action"
    else
     render action: "some_other_action"
    end
  end
end
```

When and a user creates a new account through that method and email will be send to the new account's email address with a confirmation token. That will forward the new user to a page asking them for there password.
The email template that is being send can be fond at  `app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb`

And in your routes make sure you have a post request to the controller's action.

```
post "create_new_account"      => "users#create_new_account"
```

I'm not an expert on this but the way I understand this, is that you need the confirmation option in Devise to let your new user accounts enter there own password. But since the current admin user is already logged in. You need to skip the confirmation step.

Again I'm not 100% sure this is the right way.
I would be happy to hear what other people has to say about this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try your method and will let you know.